# Styling list as float next to image

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I achieve this layout from this list:

```
<ul>
    <li id="item1">
        <span><img src="..." /></span>
        <ul id="description">
            <li class="line1">This is the first line</li>
            <li class="line2">This is the second line</li>
            <li class="line3">This is the third line</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried the float approach but it's not doing it

```
span {
    float:left;
    width:14em;
    height:14em;
}

#description {
    float:right;
    width:20em;
    margin-left:3em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got it with CSS you can edit to your liking: http://jsfiddle.net/theStudent/f69UG/3/

**CSS**

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 40em;
}
span {
    float:left;
    width:14em;
    height: 14em;
    height:14em;
    background: red;
}

#description {
    float:right;
    width:20em;
    min-height: 14em;
    margin-left:3em;
    color:#000;
}

#description > li{
    height: 4.5em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li id="item1">
        <span><img src="..." /></span>
        <ul id="description">
            <li class="line1">This is the first line</li>
            <li class="line2">This is the second line</li>
            <li class="line3">This is the third line</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't `float` the list, just the image(it has same behavior as floating an image in a paragraph, the text will wrap after the image). Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqw53/

Answer (score 0):

In this solution I'm using the `<img>` tag's attribute of `align` to align the image to the left, then the rest of the text will flow to the right.

So we have our HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/1126016138/picture?type=large" align="left" />
    <ul id="description">
        <li class="line1">This is the first line</li>
        <li class="line2">This is the second line</li>
        <li class="line3">This is the third line</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then our CSS, as bullet points aren't considered by HTML when considering spacing:

```
#description {
    list-style:none;    
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle if you want to have a look: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkX8k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

ul and img are block elements so you need to change their display type to inline-block to make sure they align horizontally

```
<ul>
    <li id="item1">
        <span><img src="..." /></span>
        <ul id="description">
            <li class="line1">This is the first line</li>
            <li class="line2">This is the second line</li>
            <li class="line3">This is the third line</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul, img{
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    float:left;
    width:14em;
    height:14em;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}
#description {
    float:right;
    margin-left:3em;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orahmax/y6P68/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can check this :

[Fidle Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/f69UG/4/)

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0

}
#item1 span {/*Span take width and height as per your image size.*/
    float:left;
    display:inlne-block;
    margin-right:20px;

}

#description {
    float:left;
    color:#333;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#description li{
    line-height:20px;
    display:block;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Good Luck...